# Unit testing DAO layer with H2 database

Tags: java, postgresql, unit-testing, h2, dao

After a lot of reading in internet, i found out that it seems to be a good practice to use a in-memory DB like H2 to unit test the DAO layer. The idea behind is to avoid working with the production DB.

Fine, so I set up a H2 DB and activated the H2 PostgreSQL Compatibility Mode, since my production DB is on Postgres. The problem I'm now facing: when I run on H2 the original SQL queries in order to build the test DB, this query is not accepted as valid by H2:

```sql
ALTER SEQUENCE MYERP.ecriture_comptable_id_seq OWNED BY MYERP.ecriture_comptable.id;
```

I guess that using the PostgreSQL Compatibility Mode is not a guarantee that all the Postgres specific syntax will be accepted by H2. And probably this would also happen with other DB such as MySQL.

So what's the point in using a h2 database in this case?
Did I miss something?

Comment: "*So what's the point in using a h2 database in this case?" - none. I never understood why people think that those would be valid tests. I for one do **not** think that using a different DBMS for testing and production is "good practice". I actually think it's useless

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit testing should focus on testing a unit. PostgreSQL is external to your application and thus trivially not part of any DAO that uses it: no 'unit test' should be written that uses any such external database.

Using the database for integration tests may be fine but as you already noticed multiple problems may arise when you use a different database to execute your integration tests (I know very little applications that only use ANSI-SQL without any triggers or other vendor specific SQL extensions like `UPSERT` in PostgreSQLs case or the SQL in your post).

So what if your production base is in-memory too? That's quite difficult and I would argue an integration test would be fine, just don't call it unit test. All of this just highlights the pain points of doing business logic in your database (e.g. through triggers that you now can't test) or using vendor specific sql which has several advantages that don't play so well with changing the underlying database vendor.

Comment: My intention was to test if all the CRUD methods of the DAO layers do the job properly. We be it's indeed more an integration test than a unit test. Anyway, instead of testing with a H2 database, i now think it would have been more meaningfull to test directly the Postgre DB. If i take care not no change the state of the DB (using rollbacks) this should be ok. What do you think?

Comment: You can always have the test start a new PostgreSQL instance in a Docker container or something, create the tables, do your tests and tear it down. Using a shared database (e.g. of a test instance) is risky as it could not be available or down for maintenanse when executing your integration tests.There is nothing wrong with a test like this though, as long as its an integration test. This kind of stuff is always annoying, even more when you don't have Docker (or something similar) around

Comment: Actually I received a demo database on Docker. So i guess I should make use of it!

Comment: Thats nice to hear, wishing you the best! Feel free to come back if you need any more help

Comment: Thanks for your help!